# « Parolante pri … »

Tags: phrase-requests, participles

Se mi parolas kun iu kaj mi volas subite ŝanĝi la temon al io nerekte rilata, mi ofte uzas esprimon kiu komenciĝas per « parolante pri … » por montri la ligon inter la du temoj, ekzemple:

> Mi pensas ke baldaŭ pluvos. Ho, **parolante pri** la vetero, ĉu vi vidis tiun televidelsendon pri klimatŝanĝo hieraŭ vespere?

Tamen mi plene konscias ke tia vortigo ne estas gramatike ĝusta ĉar participo kun e-finaĵo ĉiam devus [rilati al la subjekto de la frazo](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/e-vortoj.html#i-c5l). En ĉi tiu okazo estis mi kiu parolis pri la vetero, ne la subjekto de la frazo (« vi »). Mia fuŝa brita menso tradukas rekte de la angla per kiu oni povas senprobleme diri « speaking of the weather ».

Ĉu iu havas proponon por pli bona vortigo en tiu situacio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En via loko mi dirus senhezite:

> *Ho, **koncerne la veteron**, ĉu vi vidis...*

La foresto de *-ant-* sufiĉas ĉi tie por liberigi la adverbon. Do, aliaj ebloj estas *diskute la veteron, priparole la veteron,* ktp. aŭ simple *Pri tio* kaj *Prie, ĉu vi...*

> *Ho, pri la temo, ...*
>
> *Dum ni diskutas tion, ...*
>
> *Ho, dum temas (la vetero), ĉu vi vidis...*

Answer (score 2):

Nu, en *Lingvaj Respondoj*, mi trovas ĉi frazon uzita de Zamenhof:

> **Tuŝante la akuzativon** mi povas al vi doni la jenan konsilon [...]

Ŝajne, "tuŝante" ĉi tie estas uzata en la sama maniero kiel vi uzis la vortojn "parolante pri".

Answer (score 0):

Eble ankaux "rilate al tio" eblas?

Mi dirus "ho, kiam ni parolas pri tio, mi havas la penson ke..." (sed mi ne scias cxu estas bona Esperanto).

Comment: "rilatE al tio" estus bona ; "kiam ni parolas pri tio, ..." havas tute alian sencon, ĝi signifas ke vi havas la penson kiam vi parolas pri tio.